# How to enable TLS/SSL in java, Spring / CXF for Web Service?

Tags: java, web-services, spring, ssl, cxf

I have a simple WebService defined in Spring config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:wsa="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing"
xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:wsrm-policy="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/policy"
xmlns:wsrm-mgr="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/rm/manager"
xmlns:httpj="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
    http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/policy http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/rm/wsrm-policy.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/ws/rm/manager http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/wsrm-manager.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-*.xml" />

<bean id="logInbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
<bean id="logOutbound" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/>

<bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl">
    <property name="inInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="logInbound"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="outInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="outFaultInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="inFaultInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="logInbound"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<httpj:engine-factory bus="cxf">
    <httpj:engine port="9001">
        <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="10" maxThreads="100" />
        <httpj:connector>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
                <property name="port" value="9001" />
            </bean>
        </httpj:connector>
        <httpj:handlers>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler" />
        </httpj:handlers>
        <httpj:sessionSupport>true</httpj:sessionSupport>
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>

<bean id="serviceFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean"
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="serviceConfigurations">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceConfiguration" />
            <bean
                class="org.apache.cxf.aegis.databinding.XFireCompatibilityServiceConfiguration" />
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.service.factory.DefaultServiceConfiguration" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="eventWebService" class="org.myapp.EventWS">
    <property name="timeout" value="${timeoutWS}" />
</bean>

<jaxws:endpoint id="event" implementor="#eventWebService"
    address="${event.endpoint}">
    <jaxws:serviceFactory>
        <ref bean="serviceFactory" />
    </jaxws:serviceFactory>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

It works like a simple WS at event.endpoint=http://localhost:9001/event

But now, I want to secure that connection with TLS using server private key.
I know how to do this using SSLContext ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html ), but Spring is something new to me.
I guess I need to create a new Endpoint with another configuration? Or use another ServiceFactory?

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the engine factory with an SSL enabled connector. Maybe this helps:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL

Comment: strange, that i have to configure connector, tlsServerParameters didn't work.

<httpj:connector>
    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
     <property name="port" value="9101" />
     <property name="keystore" value= "./config/keystore-gateway" />
     <property name="password" value= "pass" />
                    <property name="keyPassword" value= "pass" />
                    <property name="needClientAuth" value= "true" />
                    <property name="wantClientAuth" value= "true" />
                    
    </bean>
   </httpj:connector>

Comment: sorry, i cannot help with the details here

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to create a new engine with SSL

```
<httpj:engine port="9101">
        <httpj:tlsServerParameters>
            <sec:clientAuthentication want="true"
                required="true" />
        </httpj:tlsServerParameters>

        <httpj:threadingParameters minThreads="10"
            maxThreads="100" />
        <httpj:connector>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
                <property name="port" value="9101" />
                <property name="keystore" value= "./config/keystore-gateway" />
                <property name="password" value= "pass" />
                <property name="keyPassword" value= "pass" />
            </bean>
        </httpj:connector>
        <httpj:handlers>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler" />
        </httpj:handlers>
        <httpj:sessionSupport>true</httpj:sessionSupport>
    </httpj:engine>
```

It works in browser with SSL.

How to enable mutual authentication now ?

Comment: strange, httpj:tlsServerParameters  didn't worked, i had to put whole configuration in httpj:connector. additional parameters for mutual authentication:

                    <property name="needClientAuth" value= "true" />
                    <property name="wantClientAuth" value= "true" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xmlns:httpj="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http-jetty/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-jetty.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:override.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" properties-ref="defaultProperties"/>
<util:properties id="defaultProperties">
    <prop key="keyManager.keystore">certs/localhost.jks</prop>
</util:properties>

<http:destination name="yourDestination" /> 

<httpj:engine-factory>
    <httpj:engine port="yourPort">
        <httpj:tlsServerParameters>
            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password" file="${keys.keystore}"/>
            </sec:keyManagers>
            <sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password" file="certs/keystore.jks"/>
            </sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                <!-- these filters ensure that a ciphersuite with
                    export-suitable or null encryption is used,
                    but exclude anonymous Diffie-Hellman key change as
                    this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks -->
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES40_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
            </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
            <!-- ### HIL 
            <sec:clientAuthentication want="true" required="true"/>
            ### HIL ENDE --> 
        </httpj:tlsServerParameters>
    </httpj:engine>
</httpj:engine-factory>
```

You need to have a keystore file such as shown on line 17. You also should have a properites file with the necessary credentials to validate against the keystore. (For a introduction into keystore and keystore authentication see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystore)